# How to set a PATH variable for selenium web drivers in windows?

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

Trying to run some old selenium scripts and keep getting stuck on.

```
 The geckodriver.exe executable could not be found on the current PATH.
```

I'm using Windows and tried adding C:\dev\selenium\ where my selenium drivers are to the Path Environment variable, but feel like I'm not doing something right. It's been forever since I've touched environmental variables.

I use node.js for selenium so, System.setProperty answers I'm finding won't work. Though I wish I could do something like that in node.

Answer (score -1):

This happening due to latest firefox doesn't support firefoxdriver, it requires to update geckodriver in your tests...

You can find latest geckodriver here https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

Then update your tests to use new geckodriver

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "PATH TO GECKO DRIVER");
DesiredCapabilities ffCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
ffCapabilities.setCapability("marionette",true);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffCapabilities);
```

Hope this helps you!!

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't, the end of my question goes... "I use node.js for selenium so, System.setProperty answers I'm finding won't work. Though I wish I could do something like that in node."

Comment: You would think... nope, did get closer though. WebDriverError: Unable to parse new session response: {"error":"unknown error","message":"Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided, and no binary flag set on the command line"}

Comment: If I try capabilities.set('firefox_binary', 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Mozilla Firefox'); I get

WebDriverError: Unable to parse new session response: {"error":"unknown error","message":"Failed to start browser:\npermission denied"}

Comment: @Serhiy Just out of curiosity, who is the "they" that "should have never done the rapid release cycle?" I'm just wanting to make sure I understand the target of your ire.

Comment: @JimEvans Whoever in the Mozilla community felt it necessary to do rapid releases like Chrome. I'm not sure who "they" are, but it must have been quite a number to break a good thing. I was perfectly happy with 2, 3, 3.5. No auto upbreaks, no rapid releases. Not that it wasn't in the decline already, but the rapid release is where we see FF #'s plummet amongst new devs. http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/  Firefox got really shitty randomly when auto-update / rapid releases happened. I had stopped using it for a long time myself.